# Use maven repo to distribute JSON Schema files

Tags: java, maven, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

In my Java microservice I want to validate my JSON objects using JSON schema.  I have a bunch of JSON Schema files. This is all fine.

Can I use a maven repo to distribute my JSON schema files then in my service add the maven dependency and select from the local schema file in my local maven repo as I need to validate JSON objects?

I know I can hold my schema files and reach out to them but I am trying to see is there some way to use maven for this?

Thanks, I hope I am clear in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution would be to simply wrap your schemas into one or more jar files and then read them as you would read any resource file.

Here is some sample code to demonstrate:

Here is a screenshot of the project structure for the schema project:

[image]

The POM for this project is extremely simple as it's just a simple jar:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>my.group</groupId>
  <artifactId>schemas</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

The project that consumes the schemas project just needs to add the dependency on the schemas project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>my.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>schema-consumer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>my.group</groupId>
            <artifactId>schemas</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The code to read the schemas is simple - as I said before it's just like reading any other resource file. Below is some sample code that reads the schema file and dumps the output to console:

```
package my.pkg;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadSchema {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputStream inStream = ReadSchema.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("schema.json");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(inStream);
        scan.useDelimiter("\\A");
        String json = scan.next();

        System.out.println(json);
        scan.close();
    }

}
```

Hope this helps!